# In scheme, is there something like an apropos command?

Tags: scheme

I know Common LISP, but mostly elisp.

Now I try to write scheme scripts to use in gimp.

And every so often when I find some function, say string-split mentioned on the net, it does not exist in gimp scheme. No idea if it really does not exist or simply has a slightly different name.

Is there something in scheme like the apropos function from elisp, where I can do (apropos "string") to get a list of all function symbols whose name contains "string"?

Edit:

I found out that my gimp versions allegedly are using tinyscheme, a *very* minimalistic implementation.

No (apropos) working, but at least good old (oblist) gives a (not so long) list of bound symbols.

Comment: It depends upon your Scheme implementation, since the R5RS standard don't mention anything ...

Comment: google brought me to https://www.seul.org/~grumbel/gimp/script-fu/script-fu-tut.html which says the apropos function exists. that's all I know about this. is it (the fucntion) no longer available?

Comment: @WillNess > (apropos "write")
Error: eval: unbound variable: apropos

Comment: thanks. so it's not available anymore...

Comment: @WillNess maybe my gip version 2.6.6 is too old.

Comment: I checked on my other box with gimp version 2.8.16, but no, unbound variable.